# Was a practice of making non-Muslims wear special markings introduced by Umar II?

Tags: history, islam

The Wikipedia page [Yellow badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_badge) says:

> The practice of wearing special markings in order to distinguish Jews
>   and other non-Muslims (Dhimmis) in Muslim-dominated countries seems to
>   have been introduced by Umayyad Caliph Umar II in early 8th century.
>   The practice was reissued and reinforced by Caliph Al-Mutawakkil
>   (847–61), subsequently remaining in force for centuries.[.2][3]

Source [3] refers to [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0003_0_01851.html):

> The introduction of a mark to distinguish persons not belonging to the religious faith of the majority did not originate in Christendom, where it was later radically imposed, but in Islam. It seems that Caliph Omar II (717–20), not Omar I, as is sometimes stated, was the first ruler to order that every non-Muslim, the dhimmī, should wear vestimentary distinctions (called giyār, i.e., distinguishing marks) of a different color for each minority group. The ordinance was unequally observed, but it was reissued and reinforced by Caliph al-Mutawakkil (847–61).

Source [.2] is,

> Antisemitism: A Historical Encyclopedia of Prejudice and Persecution,
>   Volume 1 By Richard S. Levy P:779

It [says](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=Tdn6FFZklkcC&lpg=PA779&vq=yellow%20badge&pg=PA779#v=onepage&q=779&f=false):

> In the Muslim world, specific markings were 
>    used to distinguish and humiliate individuals not 
>    belonging to the Islamic faith but dwelling 
>    within Muslim-dominated lands. The practice 
>    seems to have been introduced by the caliph 
>    Omar Il in the early eighth century, although it 
>    was unevenly applied throughout the Middle 
>    Ages.

Was a practice of making non-Muslims wear special markings introduced by Umar II?

Comment: The earliest mention of this that I could find is [The Jews of Islam Updated Edition (p25)](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10345.html)</sub>. The author gives two sources, but they are not listed in the free preview and I do not have full access to it. Older sources - eg [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=V0f4RaMNv8kC&pg=PA332&lpg=PA332&dq=Omar+II+jew&source=bl&ots=PXPTqnN4hO&sig=ad847S7XbwQ9IyKEg8RTLqNdDCw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Omar%20II%20jew&f=false) - mention other discrimination by Omar II (among them rules about clothing).

Comment: Is there any reason to doubt the claim that Umar II required Jews to be marked which seems to be well documented? Or does the claim being investigated is was he the first ruler to do so?

Comment: @Ofir well documented? Than show me that. Your argument is a argument by assertion fallacy.

Comment: You have a source in your question, what is wrong with what "Antisemitism: A Historical Encyclopedia of Prejudice and Persecution" gives? Also, if you scroll to the end of the Jewish Virtual Library article, you will see their sources as well, what is wrong with those sources? More over, it seems that the main point of debate at the sources is whether the Pact of Umar should be attributed to Umar I or Umar II, so is your question about Jews wearing special identification, or about who enacted this decree?

Comment: I edited out two problematic parts out of the question. First there is no common practice ("*the* practice") of making Jews wear a symbol. It is something despicable that happened in history ("*a* practice") multiple, presumably unrelated times. Secondly, while the original intent of the question might have been to ask about antisemitism, the actual claim you uncovered is about non-Muslims in general, so let's ask about the actual claim.

Comment: @SIMEL both sources say that it "seems" that this was the case, which seems a bit vague to me. The source I posted in my previous comment also somewhat contradicts the claims, as it talks about a ninth century caliph. I think that there is enough doubt here for a question at skeptics (although it would probably also be a good question at history).

Comment: @tim: I don't think "it seems" is really that vague here.  I read it to mean that "We know for sure that Umar II did it, but he may or may not have been the first to do so."

Comment: @tim, first we need to establish what is asked, is it a question about forcing non-muslims to wear distinctive clothes, or is it a question about who enacted the decree. If it is the later, then "seems"  may mean that most scholars think so but there is no concensus, we are talking about 1300-1400 years ago. From reading the sources, and reading about Pact of Umar, I get the impresion that the pact is atributed to Umar I, but most scholars believe that it was written by Umar II and atributed by him to Umar I. Since it's history we might never get a defenitive answer as to who wrote the pact.